# Dataframe columns does not keep order and columns with null values are excluded while writing to CosmosDB Collection

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-cosmosdb

I tried to copy data into cosmosDB collection from a dataframe in spark.
The data is writing into cosmosDB , but with two issues.

1. The order of column in dataframe is not maintaining in cosmosDB.
2. Columns with null values are not written in cosmosDB, they are totally excluded.

Below is the data available in dataframe:

```
+-------+------+--------+---------+---------+-------+
| NUM_ID|  TIME|    SIG1|     SIG2|     SIG3|   SIG4|
+-------+------+--------+---------+---------+-------+
|X00030 | 13000|35.79893| 139.9061| 48.32786|   null|
|X00095 | 75000|    null|     null|     null|5860505|
|X00074 | 43000|    null|  8.75037|  98.9562|8014505|
```

Below is the code written in spark to copy the dataframe into cosmosDB.

```
val finalSignals = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM db.tableName""")
val toCosmosDF = finalSignals.withColumn("NUM_ID", trim(col("NUM_ID"))).withColumn("SIG1", round(col("SIG1"),5)).select("NUM_ID","TIME","SIG1","SIG2","SIG3","SIG4")

//write DF into COSMOSDB

import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark._

val writeConfig = Config(Map(
      "Endpoint" -> "xxxxxxxx",
      "Masterkey" -> "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "Database" -> "xxxxxxxxx",
      "Collection" -> "xxxxxxxxx",
      "preferredRegions" -> "xxxxxxxxx",
      "Upsert" -> "true"
    ))

toCosmosDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).cosmosDB(writeConfig)
```

Below is the data written into cosmosDB.

```
    "SIG3": 48.32786,
    "SIG2": 139.9061,
    "TIME": 13000,
    "NUM_ID": "X00030",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx2a",
    "SIG1": 35.79893,
    "_rid": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "_self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "_etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1571390120
}

{
    "TIME": 75000,
    "NUM_ID": "X00095",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx2a",
    "_rid": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "SIG4": 5860505,
    "_self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "_etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1571390120
}

{
    "SIG3": 98.9562,
    "SIG2": 8.75037,
    "TIME": 43000,
    "NUM_ID": "X00074",
    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx2a",
    "SIG4": 8014505,
    "_rid": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "_self": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "_etag": "\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1571390120
}
```

1. The entry for columns with null in dataframe is missing in cosmosDB document.
2. The data written into cosmosDB is not having the column order which is there in dataframe.

How to resolve these two issues?

Comment: I do not know about **CosmosDB** but these feel like expected behavior. I doubt column order is important in any sense. And a `null` represent a value that does not exists, and on a document-like datastore that is usually represented as a non-existing field instead of a `null`.

Comment: Again, if the value is `null` why would that column name _(in the document it is called label or key)_ exist at all? If there is no value, why bother saving a `null`. Probably there is a setting to force all fields to exist and save explicit `nulls`. But that is usually a bad practice on documental data bases. Why do you care that the field exist or not? Documental databases are schemeless.

Comment: @Jay Gong- Is there any idea atleast how to maintain the order of columns?

Comment: Antony, as I already said, I do not know about **ComosDB** _(also it's been years since the last time I used **Spark**)_. I don't know, there may be a way, but I doubt. However you haven't answered my original question, why do you need this? The order in which the fields are saved shouldn't matter to you. What is the problem with them being in other order? _(leaving outside that the order of printing could be different than the order on which they are stored in disk)_.